# How to remotely get computer cpu and memory usage?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have multiple computers on my network (each of them running Windows 7), and want to remotely get the usage statistics (total CPU and memory usage of the computer) for them without actually having to log in to each and every one of them one by one.

Later I want to use this within a MATLAB script via cmd or batch files, so I prefer a programmatic check. I tried to look at windows Sysinternals, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298941/how-do-i-find-the-cpu-and-ram-usage-using-powershell

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
wmic /node:HOSTNAME cpu get loadpercentage
```

This will give you the CPU load for a remote system.

```
wmic /node:HOSTNAME OS get FreePhysicalMemory
```

This will give you free memory for a remote system.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this can be used to get info for other systems on the network?

Comment: I added the /node parameter, it's a bit rudimentary but I think it covers the question.

Comment: Remember to put the hostname in double quotes if you are just using a string and not a variable name. Otherwise you get the Invalid Global Switch error

Comment: I have an "access is denied" error message while trying this, and I don't want to mess with user settings. Is there a way getting this done without `WMIC`?

Comment: @Dominique try `typeperf` instead